# SQL how to filter out a specific row with conflicting where clause

Tags: mysql, sql, presto

This should be a simple problem but for some reason I can't get it to work. I've got a table like the following:

```
|Name|Attribute| 
----------------
|Foo |     1   |
|Foo |     2   |
|Foo |     3   |
|Bar |     1   |
|Bar |     2   |
|Bar |     3   |
|Yum |     1   |
|Yum |     2   |
|Yum |     3   |
```

I want to filter it like the following

```
|Name|Attribute| 
----------------
|Foo |     2   |
|Foo |     3   |
|Bar |     1   |
|Bar |     2   |
|Bar |     3   |
```

Note that I've removed all the "Yum" and removed a "Foo" only when Attribute = 1

Problem is that when I do something like this

```
SELECT * 
FROM table
WHERE name in ('Foo', 'Bar')
AND (name != 'Foo' AND attribute != 1)
```

I get this result

```
|Name|Attribute| 
----------------
|Bar |     2   |
|Bar |     3   |
```

I would have thought that the brackets group things together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think in terms of `or`:

```
where (name = 'Bar') or (name = 'Foo' and attribute <> 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select 
   * 
From 
   table
Where
   (Name <> 'Yum') and 
   not (Name = 'Foo' and attribute = 1)
```

Comment: This is good, but it's possible that other garbage names, (or nulls) can be added to that list so I'd avoid where Name != 'Yum" in this situation.

Comment: Well, it's your criteria. I don't have specifics for your scenario.  Good luck.